# C# Load XML file and escape characters during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to load a remote XML file using C# but there are unescaped characters (e.g. '\', '&') that are preventing the file from being loaded by my program since I keep getting the error 
"**An error occurred while parsing EntityName**"

Ideally I want to load the XML file and replace these characters during runtime so that the file is read properly.

```
 String URLString = "REMOTE XML FILE PATH";
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);                                     

 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();            

 // This is where the error is occurring
 xmlDoc.Load(URLString);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the XML file (or relevant portions)? It's plausible that the XML isn't valid (in that, it has unescaped ampersands), in which case you might have to pre-sanitize/fix the XML content before loading. EDIT: That said, IIRC, `\` isn't a character you should have to escape for. Regardless, I think we need to see the XML you're trying to load.

Comment: The XML file is very long but I think you're on the right track. What's the best way of pre-santizing the XML?

Comment: Might depend on what's in there and what's breaking. One (probably naive) way off the top of my head is to look for any instances of "&" that aren't part of a special escape sequence (`&quot; &apos; &lt; &gt; &amp;`) and replace those ampersands with `&amp;`. No idea if this will work for your specific case though; depending on how you do it, it could destroy other relevant info in the doc.

Comment: Program that generated file may need correction.